# Porting libusb code to Python: interrupt transfer

Tags: python, c++, usb, libusb

Here are two lines of code performing an interrupt transfer using libusb in C++:

```
libusb_fill_interrupt_transfer(transfer_receive, handle, LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN | USB_INTERFACE_OUT, buffer_receive, sizeof(buffer_receive), cb_in, &usb_data, 30000);
r = libusb_submit_transfer(transfer_receive);
```

How do I do the same thing in Python with PyUSB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are function `interruptWrite(self, endpoint, buffer, timeout = 100)` and `interruptRead(self, endpoint, size, timeout = 100)`, see

https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/usb/legacy.py

the `interruptRead()` function is similar to  the C++ code (poll device for interrupts, receive interrupt data from interrupt IN endpoint of device)

the `LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN | USB_INTERFACE_OUT` (`|` is bitwise OR ) in C++ is similar uses the specified USB interrupt interface `USB_INTERFACE_OUT` to query data from its specified endpoint `LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN`

in the background PyUSB uses the same function ( `write()`) for *bulk*, *interrupt* and *isochronous transfer*, only *control transfers* have special syntax. `interruptWrite()` and `interruptRead()` also use the `write()` function that abstracts the underlying native USB tranfer types

> USB  has four flavors of transfers: bulk, interrupt, isochronous and
>   control. [ ... ]
>
> Control transfer is the only transfer that has structured data
>   described in the spec, the others just send and receive raw data from
>   USB point of view. Because of it, you have a different function to
>   deal with control transfers, all the other transfers are managed by
>   the same functions.
>
> You issue a control transfer through the `ctrl_transfer` method. It is
>   used both for OUT and IN transfers. The transfer direction is
>   determined from the `bmRequestType` parameter.

source: https://github.com/walac/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst

in general the device only answers on an interrupt transfer if it has interrupts pending, so the host polls the device for interrupts with an interrupt transfer. this becomes obvious in the C++ code that sends an interrupt request (transfer) and awaits to receive an answer

http://mvidner.blogspot.com/2017/01/usb-communication-with-python-and-pyusb.html